# Whether can TLS client send `Encrypted Alert` to server?

Tags: tls

I often see TLS server -> client: `Encrypted Alert` package for closing the TCP connection.

[image]

whether can TLS client send `Encrypted Alert` to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically an "Encrypted Alert" is a TLS notification. In your case the notification is that the session is stopping, as the following message
is a FIN packet.

This message is used by the TLS protocol for notifying the peer
that the connection can be closed,
usually when there is no more traffic to send.

It is used in SSL/TLS for notifying to close the connection.
It's quit normal to see it at the end of a SSL/TLS session.

An Encrypted Alert in general is a notification to the peer,
which can be for a change in status or for an error condition.

For more information and the complete list of alerts :

- [SSL/TLS Alert Protocol and the Alert Codes](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/ssl-tls-alert-protocol-and-the-alert-codes/ba-p/377132)
- [How TLS/SSL Works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc783349(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: so, both client and server can send this `Encrypted Alert`, right?

Comment: Yes. I added more info to my answer.